# Ionic splash screen hides too quickly testflight

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, testflight

I am running into an issue where when I open my app in Testflight, the splash screen hides and then there is just a white screen before the app loads.

I have this in my app.js:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }, 3000);
 });
})
```

And this in config file:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash"/>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4000"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1"/>
```

The splash screen hides normally when I run my app through the emulator, its just when I run it in Testflight that it breaks. Neither the config nor app.js seem to have any effect on how long the splash screen shows on Testflight.

If anyone has any advice I'd really appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

my splashscreen configuration is as below and it works fine without any issue

*nothing i added in app.js*

i added [this plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen) to my ionic project.
I copied my **res/** folder into my project root folder which has all splashscreen `drawable-` files in respective folders inside

in **config.xml**

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true|false" />

<platform name="android">
    //then added all dpi as this

    <splash src="res/drawable-land-hdpi/screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>

</platform>
```